# React form refreshing the page despite being told not to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a form in a react project that is behaving a bit strange. I have e.preventDefault() attatched to my submit button but for some reason the page is still refreshing each time the button is clicked. Could someone please help me figure out why this is happening? Here is the Component in question:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './PostForm.css';
import axios from 'axios'

const PostForm = () => {

  const [posts, setPost] = useState({
    body: '',
    author: 'Michael',
  });

const onChange = (e) =>{
    setPost({...posts, [e.target.name] : e.target.value})

}

const sendPost = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  try {
    const res = axios.post('http://localhost:4000/post', posts);
  console.log(res)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    
  }
  
}

  return (
    <form className="formContainer">
      <div className="form">
        <textarea className='formBody' type="text" placeholder="What's new?" name='body' onChange={onChange} />
       
        <button onSubmit={sendPost}>Share</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default PostForm;
```

Comment: `onSubmit` needs to be on the `<form>` and not some random `<button>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onSubmit should be in the form tag. And change the button to input and it's type as submit.

```
    <form className="formContainer" onSubmit={sendPost}>
      <div className="form">
        <textarea className='formBody' type="text" placeholder="What's new?" name='body' onChange={onChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Share" />
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much...it's the small things like that. I had a couple other forms in my app where I didn't label them as form and therefore they worked as expected with the above layout. Didn't realize there was a difference.